# Loading Image into byte array in entity bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring data jpa and hibernate to retrieve entities from a DB table. One of the entity fields is the path to an image which is located on the filesystem. is it possible to load the image as a byte array into an entity? e.g

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   int id;
   String name;
   String pictureName;

   @Transient
   byte[] image;

   // other properties
   public void setPictureName(String pictureName)
   {
        String path="D:\\images\\";
        File f = new File(path + pictureName);
        this.image = new byte[(int)f.length()];

        FileUtility.toByteArray(f,this.image); //custom class

        this.picture = picture;
   }
//other stuff
}
```

i tried that with JPA but the byte array image field always comes as null while everything else is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you have to map whatever column has the picture name so Hibernate can populate it.

Thus, if you have a column called "picture_name" then your entity should have:

```
@Column(name="picture_name")
private String pictureName;
```

Then, when Hibernate loads the Entity, it will call the `setPictureName` method and run your code to load the file into the byte array.